# How to restructure and filter Kubernetes logs in Fluent Bit to output as structured JSON?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, fluentd, elk

I am sending all my logs from the EKS cluster to newrelic using fluent bit but the log is messed up right now and looks like

```
{"date":1684914692.550265,"log":"2023-05-24T07:51:32.550162086Z stdout F {\"level\":\"info\",\"ts\":\"2023-05-24T07:51:32.550Z\",\"msg\":\"history worker 1\"}", "container_name":"test"}
```

But I want it to look like

```
{"date":1684914692.550265,"level":"info","ts":"2023-05-24T07:51:32.550Z","msg":"history worker 1","container_name":"test"}
```

So basically I want to trim the string (`2023-05-24T07:51:32.550162086Z stdout F`) inside **log** key and parse the json so that all the key value pairs are in the final output json.

I have also tried using the fluent bit kubernetes filter plugin

```
[FILTER]
    Name           kubernetes
    Match          kube.*
    Kube_URL       https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
    Buffer_Size    ${K8S_BUFFER_SIZE}
    merge_log      On
    K8S-Logging.Exclude ${K8S_LOGGING_EXCLUDE}
    Labels         Off
    Annotations    Off
```

but merge_log only works if the log contains pure json.